# [Python]Selenium keyword in Robot Framework to click span role="button" inside <a> tag

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I want to automate a *Download* scenario.

This is the snippet/part of the webpage:

```
<div id="widget-header-1" class="right-header">
<a id="Edit-icon-1" href="#" class="widget-button">     
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil ui-state-default" role="button" alt="Edit" title="Edit"></span></a><a id="Email-icon-1" href="#" class="widget-button">     
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed ui-state-default" role="button" alt="Email" title="Email"></span>
</a>
<a id="Download-icon-1" href="#" class="widget-button">     
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s ui-state-default" role="button" alt="Download" title="Download">
</span>
</a>
<a href="/dashboard_widgets/1" class="widget-button">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin ui-state-default" role="button" alt="Zoom In" title="Zoom In">
</span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="widget-button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash           ui-state-default" role="button" alt="Delete" title="Delete">
</span>
</a>
</div>
```

And in my robot framework code, I have used :

```
Click Button    //span[@class="ui-icon.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s.ui-state-default"]
```

But when I run it on RIDE, I get the error:.

```
Button with locator '//span[@class="ui-icon.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s.ui-state-default"]' not found.
```

Using the same with `//*span` throws the error:
`The string '//*span[@class="ui-icon.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s.ui-state-default"]' is not a valid XPath expression.`

I have tried with the below xpaths too, but no luck:

```
//*[@id="Download-icon-1"]/span
```

Gives error `Button with locator '//*[@id="Download-icon-1"]/span' not found.`

```
//a[@class="ui-icon.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s.ui-state-default"]/span
```

Gives error  :  `Button with locator '//a[@class="ui-icon.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s.ui-state-default"]/span' not found.`

Even if I use `Click Link` I see an error:
`Link with locator '//a[@class="ui-icon.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s.ui-state-default"]' not found.`

Answer (score 1):

`Click Button` is used only for elements of type `<button>` - your targeted one is `<span>`.
In the html source you've shown the class value is `"ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s ui-state-default"`, but you have changed every space character with a dot - that won't work.
`//*span` is indeed an invalid xpath, thus the error - an asterisk is a node name by itself ("any type"), it's not used as a (wildcard?) prefix.

Change it with this:

```
Click Element    //span[@class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s ui-state-default"]
```

, or:

```
Click Element    //*[@id="Download-icon-1"]/span
```

, as long as those class/id values are not randomly generated on reload, these 2 calls should work.

Overall, `Click Element` doesn't care what is the type of the target elements - it just clicks, contrary to `Click Button`.